# Jenkins - Username and Password to checkout git in Jenkinsfile (groovy)

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy

We are trying to use AWS DynamoDB (with KMS encrypted values) to store our secrets rather than using Jenkins Credentials. This is advised by our security team.

I am able to fetch secrets (git username and password) as variables on Jenkins slaves, but not sure how to use those to *checkout* git repository using those.

This is our existing code

```
stage('SCM Checkout') {
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "*/${GIT_BRANCH}"]],
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [],
        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'GIT_PASSWORD', url: "${GIT_URL}"]]])
}
```

I want to use variable GIT_USER and GIT_PASSWORD (fetched from AWS) instead of using *credentialsId*

Comment: Have you tried the `user:password@git.example.com` syntax for the URL?

Comment: I think it will be easier for you to work with SSH key.

Comment: @StephenKing Yeah, that works but then the credentials are exposed as plain text in console of Jenkins jobs

Comment: Even if you use groovy script you can get any password you want. If you restrict the credentials plugin then you cannot use crentials to a script

Comment: @LefterisBab Can you please give an example? Thanks!

Comment: import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.* 
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
def jenkinsCredentials = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
        com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class,
        Jenkins.instance,
        null,
        null
);
for (creds in jenkinsCredentials) {
  if(creds.id=="username") {
   println(creds.username)
   println(creds.password)
   break;
  }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have finally come up with a solution by using SSH Key. In my server startup script ([AWS user data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)), I have fetched (from DynamoDB) keys and username of my Git Repository ([AWS CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/)) and stored them in `~/.ssh/sshkey` and `~/.ssh/config` files respectively.

Here, is my `~/.ssh/config` file

```
Host git-codecommit.<my_aws_region>.amazonaws.com
  User <my_user>
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/sshkey
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

And, here is the stage to *checkout* git repository.

```
stage('Checkout SCM') {
    git url: 'ssh://git-codecommit.<my_aws_region>.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<my_repo>', branch: '<my_branch>'
}
```

This is not exactly what I was looking for in the starting, but solves my issue.